# How to get Facebook Alternate Name via Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API and Facebook Connect to make an authentication system in Wordpress. The Connect part goes all ok, the Facebook Graph goes ok as well.

But: How do I fetch the Facebook Alternate Name? I searched the docs at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/, but found no trace of it. Any ideas?

The main idea is that privacy is a concern, and the system goes better nickname based than just last name based. If the Alternate Name is empty I just ask the user to enter a nickname.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem, I have found no way of getting the alternative name in the Graph API, I use the Java version (RestFB).

Comment: No, I have not found any solutions. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not exposed yet, when i was looking for this, i made a work around...

I know that if you use the `search_tokens` field at `user` table, the array will have the alternate name... If you have luck, the array will contain the `first`, `middle`, `last`, and the `alternative` name, so, compare the arrays to the names, and exclude the know names, the other one is the alternative name....

Look this bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/371978199536659/