# How to get translated user name from facebook?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

My android application uses Facebook SDK. I want to know, is it possible to get friend's name in two languages. For example, my friend have two name options in Facebook, english version and russian version. So I want to get russian version of name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know if this works for usernames (didn´t even know it is possible to define them in different languages), but normally you get translated data by adding a locale parameter to an API call. For example:

```
/me?locale=de_DE
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible directly as explained here: [How to get Facebook Alternate Name via Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606784/how-to-get-facebook-alternate-name-via-graph-api) but the answer there does have a workaround that doesn't sound that promising.

Also look at the bug report that post refers to, it was closed and nothing done with it.